# If $cos(A-B)+cos(B-C)+cos(C-A)=\frac {-3}{2}$, prove that $cosA+cosB+cosC=sinA+sinB+sinC=0$

Tags: trigonometry

If $$cos(A-B)+cos(B-C)+cos(C-A)=\frac {-3}{2}$$ prove
that $$cosA+cosB+cosC=sinA+sinB+sinC=0$$

My Attempt:

$$cos(A-B)+cos(B-C)+cos(C-A)=\frac {-3}{2}$$
$$cosA \cdot cosB+sinA \cdot sinB+cosB \cdot cosC+sinB  \cdot sinC+cosC \cdot cosA+sinC \cdot sinA=\frac {-3}{2}$$.

How should I go further? Please help me with a simple method.

Comment: First thing I thought of: with the sum-to-product formula $\cos(a) + \cos(b) = 2 \cos(\frac{a+b}{2})\cos(\frac{a-b}{2})$, we have
$$
2 \left[ 
\cos(A - B) + \cos(B - C) + \cos(C - A)
\right] = \\
[\cos(A - B) + \cos(B - C)]+
[\cos(B - C) + \cos(C - A)] + 
[\cos(C - A) + \cos(A - B)] =\\
2\left[\cos[(C - A)/2]\cos(B) 
 + \cos[(B - A)/2]\cos(C)
 + \cos[(C-B)/2]\cos(A) \right]
$$
I don't know if that helps, though

Comment: $A, B, C$ are the angles of a triangle?

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom, I could not understand. Please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: @Eugen Covaci, Not specified in the question!

Comment: What is up with the title. what goes after that first equals sign?

Comment: @The Count, Please check the edited version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Continuing from where we left off, we have that

$$ 2(\cos a \cos b + \sin a \sin b + \cos b \cos c + \sin b \sin c + \cos c \cos a + \sin c \sin a) + 3 = 0. $$

Now we write $3$ as $(\cos^2 a + \sin^2 a) + (\cos^2 b + \sin^2 b) + (\cos^2 c + \sin^2 c) $ and substitute this in. We then make use of the identity

$$ (x + y + z)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2(xy + yz + zx) $$

to obtain that

$$ (\cos a + \cos b + \cos c)^2 + (\sin a + \sin b + \sin c)^2 = 0 $$

from which the claim follows easily.

Comment: I used a similar technique as Dylan's above but he got in first :-)

I also looked at this geometrically. There is a similar claim for the complex third roots of unity and the complex third roots of z.

The result will be true if A = x , B = x + $2 \pi /3$, and C = x - $2 \pi /3$ or (coterminal) C = x + $4 \pi/3$,  so that A - B = $-2 \pi /3$, B - C = $4 \pi/3$

Comment: Re-try 

I used a similar technique as Dylan's above but he got in first :-)

I also looked at this geometrically. There is a similar claim for the complex third roots of unity and the complex third roots of z.

The above claimswill be true if A = x + $2 \pi /3$ , B = $x $, and C = x - $2 \pi /3$ or (coterminal) C = x + $4 \pi/3$,  so that A - B = $2 \pi /3$, B - C = $2 \pi/3$, and C - A  =  $-4\pi /3$ or $2 \pi /3$  (Think I got the signs right this time.)

Question -- is there any other solution?

Comment: @victoria Those are indeed the only solutions. (Up to adding multiples of $2 \pi$.)

Comment: Thank you. Is there any not-too-advanced way to prove uniqueness?

Comment: Yes. Let $x = e^{i A}, y = e^{iB}$, and $z = e^{iC}$. Then the answer shows that $x + y + z = 0$, and so $x + y$ lies on the unit circle. (Since it is equal to $-z$.) Let $\theta$ be the angle between the segment from $0$ to $x$ and the segment from $0$ to $y$. Then $\theta$ is also the angle formed by the segment from $x$ to $x + y$, and the segment from $y$ to $x +y$, and is twice the angle formed by the segments from $x$ to $z$ and from $y$ to $z$. We get that $\theta + \theta/2 = \pi$, and so $\theta = \pi/3$. (It would be a lot clearer with a picture.)